# How to consume SOAP web service from .NET Core 3.0 WPF app

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I have a SOAP web service. I want to consume it in my WPF app. I am using .NET Core 3.0, Visual Studio 2019. So I used the Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider to add reference to my project.  This created the following classes: [image: picture1] 
and [image]

Now, how do I use these to get my data by calling the web service?  I tried the following; is this the correct way to call the web service?  In many examples that I have seen on the internet, the client constructor does not need the EndpointConfiguration parameter.  Why is this required in my case?   Can I use the InsertRecordResponse class directly without creating the 'client' first? If yes, how would I do that (to keep the code simpler). Finally, what is the use for InsertRecordRequest and InsertRecordRequestBody and what is the differnce?

```
  var client = new mserviceSoapClient(mserviceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.mserviceSoap);
  Task<InsertRecordResponse> x = client.InsertRecordAsync("", "",     "", "", "",""); //call InsertRecord asynchronously
```

Comment: You should create a client and you should await the insert method. The constructor parameter depends on the SOAP version supported, in your case you can choose. And you probably have to give the request as an argument to the insert method. The body is probably needed as a member of the request.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you checked the Always Generate Message Contract option when you generated the client proxy class. Usually this is not necessary. You can directly generate asynchronous methods and use the asynchronous programming model to build your application logic. This does not cause a delay crash of WPF.
[image]
You could also generate synchronous methods by selected the below option, just like the dotnetframework-based project.
[image]
Besides, Dotnetframework-based projects can be configured directly from webconfig files. Since this project is Core-based, no webconfig file is generated, so the default constructor takes a parameter. This parameter specifies an enumeration, and the constructor gets endpoint and binding information based on the enumeration type.
[image]
Please refer to my example.

```
//with Message Contract
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client(ServiceReference1.Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService1);
var request = new ServiceReference1.GetDataRequest(34);
var response1 = client.GetDataAsync(request);
MyLabel.Content = response1.Result.GetDataResult;

//Without checked MessageContract
ServiceReference2.Service1Client client1 = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client(ServiceReference2.Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService1);
var response2 = client1.GetDataAsync(34);
MyLabel.Content += " " + response2.Result;
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: How would you provide your own endpoint url and thus override the generic one in the generated reference code class? The EndPoint is now an enum of EndPointConfiguration.