# WSDL import in .NET CORE 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, wsdl

i am new to .net core 3.1

I have the following problem, when I reference a WSDL and it creates the reference, when I am trying to start the webservice it asks me for an "Endpointconfiguration" in the constructor that I don't know what it is or how to create it.

```
WSMP.Service1SoapClient WS = new WSMP.Service1SoapClient();
```

[example constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydNm0.png)

ty

***UPDATE***

I used this constructor for the service, but I get the error attached in the image, in .net it works without problem but in .net core it doesn't work, I don't know if I have something wrong in the configuration of the new Service1SoapClient (basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress));

```
 public class SoapMultiPay : ISoapDemoApiMp
{
    public readonly string serviceUrl = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxx/Service1.asmx";
    public readonly EndpointAddress endpointAddress;
    public readonly BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding;

    public SoapMultiPay()
    {
        endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);
        basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
        basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        basicHttpBinding.AllowCookies = true;
    }
    public async Task<Service1SoapClient> GetInstanceAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => new Service1SoapClient(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress));
    }
    public async Task<RespuestaCotizadorGiro> GetCotizadorGiro(string zipCode)
    {
        var client = await GetInstanceAsync();
        var response = await client.CotizadorGiroAsync(null, null);
        return response;
    }
}
```

[Update-errorClientWs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJkQw.png)

Comment: Based on your description, I try to create a web service, and [use the WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) to add web service reference, then, I could use the service client success, you could check [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glfof.png). 
Try to use above steps to recheck your web service, if still not working, perhaps the service client instance needs an argument, please check constructors and add parameters.

Comment: hello update the question thank you very much @ZhiLv

Comment: It seems that your WSDL contains multiple endpoint, in this scenario, when you create the service client instance, you have to assign the endpoint, try to use the code like this: `ServiceReference2.Service1Client client1 = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client(ServiceReference2.Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService1);
var response2 = client1.GetDataAsync(34);
MyLabel.Content += " " + response2.Result;`. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445647/how-to-consume-soap-web-service-from-net-core-3-0-wpf-app

Comment: yup, thats work !!!!!!

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssss!!

Comment: Congratulations! I will organize a reply according to the solution, and I hope you could mark it as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your WSDL contains multiple endpoint, in this scenario, when you create the service client instance, you have to assign the endpoint, try to use the code like this:

```
ServiceReference2.Service1Client client1 = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client(ServiceReference2.Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService1); 
var response2 = client1.GetDataAsync(34); 
MyLabel.Content += " " + response2.Result;
```

More details information, you could check this thread:

[How to consume SOAP web service from .NET Core 3.0 WPF app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445647/how-to-consume-soap-web-service-from-net-core-3-0-wpf-app)